# Spring Starter Project missing builder when creating project

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven, spring-tool-suite

My STS Version: 3.7.1.RELEASE, Build Id: 201510041213, Platform: Eclipse Mars.1 (4.5.1) does not create the correct project when selecting for instance Spring Starter Project.
When comparing with one of my existing projects I can see that there are missing Builders. The created project does only contain a Maven Builder.
My reference project has Maven, Java and Spring Project Builders.

I have installed a fresh version of STS with my plugins (Findbugs, JAutodoc, ObjectAid).

Usually STS creates a Spring/Java/maven enabled project abd starts downloading resources and builds the structure accordingly but not in my IDE.

Anyone else has/have has this issue before?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was related to .metadata in the workspace.
Creating a new workspace solved this issue